# Can't understand python variable scopes for callbacks and with blocks

Tags: python-3.x

While writing a function that will show a progress bar while downloading a list of files from an ftp server I ended up with some strange script:

```py
with ftplib.FTP(...) as ftp:
  files = list(ftp.mlsd(path=remote_dir_path))
  total_size = sum(int(f[1]['size']) for f in files)
  total_done = 0
  current_done = 0
  current_size = 0

  def callback(chunk):
    global current_done
    global total_done
    global current_size
    global total_size
    trg_file.write(chunk) # how? why it knows what is `trg_file`?
    current_done += len(chunk)
    total_done += len(chunk)
    print_progressbar(current_done,total_done,...)

  for file in files:
    current_done = 0
    current_size = int(file[1]['size'])
    with open(file[0],'wb') as trg_file:
      ftp.retrbinary('RETR %s/%s'%(remote_dir_path,file[0]),callback)
```

I had to write `global` in `callback` function so that python does not complain about it. BUT it knew what is `trg_file` no problem?!?!?!
Trying to understand I wrote a small test:

```py
def callback():
  print(foo)

def main():
  foo = 'FOOOO'
  callback()

main()
```

It failed as expected.

I get why the second script does not work. Intuition says that the first should not work too. But it works. Can somebody please explain why?
EDIT:
The question is not about `global` itself, but about `with ... as ...` block and scope (scope of `... as variable` variable)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Use of "global" keyword in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4693120/use-of-global-keyword-in-python)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you do something like this:

```
def abc():
    x = 5
```

The `x` variable is local, same applies to

```
def abc():
    x += 5
```

Because it basically is `x = x + 5`, assign operator again.
Consider this one:

```
x = 1
def abc():
    print(x)
```

What will hapen here? `x` will be printed because x is available in the abc function scope.

Now consider this one:

```
x = 1
def abc():
    print(x)
    x = 5
    print(x)

abc()
```

What will happen? Will the first print print 1? The answer is **no** because later on in the function definition there is `x = 5`, so  `x` will be treated as a local variable in **whole** the function, the first print included - it won't look to global scope, because there is an `x` variable in local scope. It wasn't assign yet when first print is executed, that's why there will be an error.

Now `with` statement doesn't create a scope. That's why you need `global` keyword if you want to assign to (global) variables: `total_size, total_done, current_done, current_size`.

To ilustrate why some variables doesn't need `global` keyword consider this snippet:

```
some_list = [1, 2, 3]
def abc():
    some_list = ['a', 'b', 'c']  # assignment to variable some_list, it is 
                                 # a local variable, it has nothing to do
                                 # with global some_list (it references a different object)
    print(some_list)

abc()
print(some_list)
>>> ['a', 'b', 'c']
>>> [1, 2, 3]

def cba():
    some_list.append(4)  # now there is no assignment so some_list is a global variable and references the same object in memory from the beginning

cba()
print(some_list)
>>> [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

If it's still confusing, there is this nice website when you can visualize which variable references which object in memory here: http://pythontutor.com/visualize.html.

Comment: So, `for` does not create it's own scope -> assignments in its' body are global. And `with ... as var` does not create a scope and is something similar to `var = ...`, which is also a global variable. `callback` is called after `with ... as trg_file` and in the same scope. If that's correct, then it makes sense. Thank you!

Comment: Not sure what you mean by callback :p

Comment: I mean the function named `callback`. It's defined at the same level as `try_file`, which in this case is global for both of them. So the `callback` function has the access to `tag_file` because it does not define it locally inside its' body. And since `callback` is called after `tag_file` is assigned (with the help as `with...` construction), so the `callback` has read access to it! Correct? =)

Comment: Any way, that `with...` construction made it look like the second script from the question, and your explanation helped to understand what is really happening! Thanks!